# Having difficulty getting an actionButton in a nested Shiny module to work

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

In the following modularized shiny app the insertBtn_outer button works okay, but I am struggling to get the insertBtn_inner button to work. Many thanks for any insights that could help to resolve my issue.

```r
library(shiny)

innerUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns('insertBtn_inner'), 'Insert')
}

inner <- function(input,output,session){
  observeEvent(input$insertBtn_inner, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = 'Debug message',
      paste0('The inner button works'),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))})
}

outerUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns('insertBtn_outer'), 'Insert'),
    br(),
    tabsetPanel(id=ns('tabset'), type = 'tabs',
                innerUI('inner1')))
}

outer <- function(input,output,session){
  callModule(inner,'inner1')
  observeEvent(input$insertBtn_outer, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = 'Debug message',
      paste0('The outer button works'),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL))})
}  


ui <- shiny::navbarPage('test_app',
                        shiny::tabPanel('Tab Panel',
                                        outerUI('test')))

server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(outer,'test')
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a `tabsetPanel`, you must use one or more `tabPanel`. In addition you have to call the `innerUI` with `ns`, that is `innerUI(ns('inner1'))`.

```
outerUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns('insertBtn_outer'), 'Insert'),
    br(),
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("XXX", innerUI(ns('inner1'))), 
                id=ns('tabset'), type = 'tabs')
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stéphane. I had inadvertently removed the tabPanel() call when I created this minimum reproducible example (apologies for that). Pointing out this particular missing ns() call has really removed the roadblocks I was facing.