# Nested Modules and ObserveEvents - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I previously asked a similar question but didn't have any luck.

I've put together a simple full app in hope that this may help people to solve my question/issue.

In this app, I want to dynamically create UI within a module and each set of dynamically generate UI should be reactive to other components within the same namespace.

In this example, I want each column value input to be reactive to the value of the column selector in the same namespace.

To make things simple, the column value input should be update to the current value of the column selector input.

This is where I am having issues. I can't get the dynamically generate UI elements to update

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")



#UI elements
outerUI<-function(id){
 
    
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    tagList(
        actionButton(inputId=ns("addItem"), "Add New Item"),
        div(id = ns('innerModulePlaceholder'))
    )
}




#####sever code inner UI

innerUiTemplate<-function(id, data){
    
    ns=NS(id)
    
    
    
    
    fluidRow(
        
        
        
        
        pickerInput(  inputId=ns("columnSelector"),
                      label = "Select Column",
                      choices=colnames(data),
                      selected = NULL,
                      multiple = FALSE 
                      
        ),
        br(),
        
        pickerInput(  inputId=ns("ValueSelector"),
                      label = "Select Values",
                      choices= NULL,
                      selected = NULL,
                      multiple = FALSE
        )
        
    )
    
    
    
}

#updates
innerServer<-function(id,data){
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            
            ns <-session$ns
            
            
            observeEvent(input$columnSelector,{
                
                
                
                updatePickerInput(
                    session,
                    inputId="ValueSelector",
                    choices = input$columnSelector
                    
                )
            })
            
            
            
        }
    )
}









##########server code - outer UI

outerServer<-  function(id,data){
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            
            
            counter<-reactiveValues()
            
            counter$count=0
            
            ns <-session$ns
            
            
            
            
            observeEvent(input$addItem, {
                
                counter$count=counter$count+1
                insertUI(selector=paste0("#",ns("innerModulePlaceholder")),where="afterEnd", innerUiTemplate(id=paste0("innerModule", counter$count ), data) )
                innerServer(id=paste0("innerModule", counter$count ), data )
                
                
                
            }
            
            
            )
            
            
            
        }
        
    )
}






#mainUI

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("Module")
)

# main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    data<-reactive({
        
        column1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
        column2<-c(5,6,7,4,2)
        data<-data.frame(column1, column2)
        
        return(data)
    })
    
    output$Module <-renderUI({
        outerUI(id="firstTime" ) 
        
    })
    outerServer(id="firstTime", data() )
}
    
    # run app
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: After a lot of googling I found this answer which I will try tomorrow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237190/having-difficulty-getting-an-actionbutton-in-a-nested-shiny-module-to-work. Could be that the inner module server needs to be part of the outer module namespace . Also will check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648298/using-shinys-updateselectinput-within-nested-modules

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `ns()` in the `innerUiTemplate` call you need to use `data[[input$columnSelector]]` in the `updatePickerInput` choices.

```
#updates
innerServer<-function(id,data, var){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      observeEvent(eventExpr = input$columnSelector, handlerExpr = {
        #if (!is.null(input$columnSelector)) mychoices$col <- data[[input$columnSelector]]
        updatePickerInput(
          session,
          inputId="ValueSelector",
          choices = data[[input$columnSelector]]
        )
      })

    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, slight nuance in calling the insert UI function

````
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
 
 
#UI elements
outerUI<-function(id){
 
    
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    tagList(
        actionButton(inputId=ns("addItem"), "Add New Item"),
        div(id = ns('innerModulePlaceholder'))
    )
}
 
 

#####sever code inner UI
 
innerUiTemplate<-function(id, data){
    
    ns=NS(id)
    
    
    
    
    fluidRow(
        
        
        
        
        pickerInput(  inputId=ns("columnSelector"),
                      label = "Select Column",
                      choices=colnames(data),
                      selected = NULL,
                      multiple = FALSE 
                      
        ),
        br(),
        
        pickerInput(  inputId=ns("ValueSelector"),
                      label = "Select Values",
                      choices= NULL,
                      selected = NULL,
                      multiple = FALSE
        )
        
    )
    
    
    
}
 
#updates
innerServer<-function(id,data){
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            
            ns <-session$ns
            
            
            observeEvent(input$columnSelector,{
                
              
                
                updatePickerInput(
                    session,
                    inputId="ValueSelector",
                    choices = input$columnSelector
                    
                )
            })
            
            
            
        }
    )
}
 
 
 
 
 
##########server code - outer UI
 
outerServer<-  function(id,data){
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            
            
            counter<-reactiveValues()
            
            counter$count=0
            
            ns <-session$ns
            
            
            
            
            observeEvent(input$addItem, {
               
                counter$count=counter$count+1
                insertUI(selector=paste0("#",ns("innerModulePlaceholder")),where="afterEnd", innerUiTemplate(id=ns(paste0("innerModule", counter$count )), data) )
                innerServer(id=paste0("innerModule", counter$count ), data )
                
                
                
            }
            
            
            )
            
            
            
        }
        
    )
}
 
 
 

#mainUI
 
ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("Module")
)
 
# main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    data<-reactive({
        
        column1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
        column2<-c(5,6,7,4,2)
        data<-data.frame(column1, column2)
        
        return(data)
    })
    
    output$Module <-renderUI({
        outerUI(id="firstTime" ) 
        
    })
    outerServer(id="firstTime", data() )
}
    
    # run app
    shinyApp(ui, server)
    
    ```
````